# How do I avoid the "S to Skip" message on boot?

Tags: boot, filesystem, fstab

After upgrading my laptop from karmic to lucid, my fat32 partition won't mount automatically. I get the message:

```
The disk drive for /osshare is not ready yet or not present
Continue to wait; or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

Funny thing is, if I skip, then `/osshare/` is mounted once I log in.

I've a similar setup on my desktop, and it works fine. Fstab on desktop:

```
UUID=4663-6853  /osshare        vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1
```

`/etc/fstab` on laptop:

```
UUID=1234-5678 /osshare vfat utf8,auto,rw,user 0 0
```

Comment: What happens when you mount the disk manually in Ubuntu? (`sudo mount /ossshare`)

Comment: That's the thing, I don't need to. Once I press S to skip and login, /osshare is mounted.

Comment: Related: [/etc/fstab skip on error](http://serverfault.com/q/466110/130437) at SF

Comment: This question belongs on [unix.se]

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should add the option `nobootwait` to your `/etc/fstab`. So that it looks like:

```
UUID=1234-5678 /osshare vfat utf8,auto,rw,user,nobootwait 0 0
```

From `fstab(5)`:

> The  `mountall(8)` program that mounts filesystem during boot also recognises additional options that the  ordinary  `mount(8)`  tool  does  not.
>          These  are:  `bootwait`  which  can  be applied to remote filesystems
>          mounted outside of `/usr` or `/var`, without which `mountall(8)`  would  not
>          hold up the boot for these; `nobootwait` which can be applied to non-remote filesystems to explicitly instruct `mountall(8)` not  to  hold  up
>          the boot for them;

Comment: Does not work here my cifs mount option list looks like: auto,nofail,nobootwait,credentials=/etc/mycred and the message still appears

Comment: Thanks! `nobootwait` is a good idea for extra EBS volumes mounted on EC2 instances, too.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, just remove the entry for the offending disk from your fstab. Then at least you can start from scratch if there is a deeper problem. Obviously this is not appropriate for your `/boot` `/swap` or `/` partitions, though.

Answer (score 10):

Another option for `/etc/fstab` mounts appears to be the "**bg**" option, which not only backgrounds the `nfs` mount, but also attempts retries at a regular interval after boot finishes.  So when the `nfs` server comes back online, your mounts will eventually come back online.

Comment: Any link to the documentation? This only applies to NFS-mounts?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you might need to edit your fstab tables as an extra drive is messing with your boot-up, give the following a try:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type `gksudo nautilus` and hit the run button
3. Navigate to `/etc/fstab`
4. Open file and edit out the extra drive that is launching
5. Save the file when done and close
6. Restart machine

This should stop the extra drive from interrupting your boot-up process.

Comment: Quicker: `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the options from `auto` to `noauto`

Comment: Will that not mean I'll need to mount the partition manually once I log in?

Comment: I'm not sure I don't recall that specific options repercussions. However comparing the fstab line from your desktop and the one on your laptop I would try removing the `auto` option all together.

Comment: Yes, you will have to mount it manually.

Comment: You can use gvfs-mount to automatically mount the partition after you log in (call it from Startup Applications).

Comment: The auto type lets the mount command guess what type of file system is used. I dont think it has anything to do in breaking your system in case of bad disk.