# Don't wait for user input on errors while booting

Tags: 11.04, server, boot, headless

I'm running 11.04 server, headless, and at a certain point it didn't boot anymore: it just stopped. It seems like I made a mistake with some of the disks, the fstab or the raid config, anycase one of the arrays couldn't be mounted.

What happens is that there is some fancy screen (too fancy for my old LCD, but that's another question) saying `Couldn't mount /foobar. Press s to continue or [..]`.

What I want is that it continues automatically. If I reboot I should check if that worked, fine, but I don't want to guess what button to press for it to continue, and I certainly don't want to have to run it with some sort of screen. Obviously, if `/` fails to mount then moving on is kinda hard to do. Ok. I get it, but when some raid doesn't come up, I have to boot to fix it.

**How can I have ubuntu server 11.04 skip all but the fatal errors?**

Comment: Please keep a review of the question and occasionally modify it with more information just so that the question pops to the top of the active list.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're getting at. I could add fake and random information, but the question seems clear enough. I have neither a sollution, nor has the need for one gone away.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I avoid the "S to Skip" message on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After A LOT of looking around I came across a Ubuntu Forums question that should solve your issue;

> Fixed it by editing /etc/fstab
>
> Edit the line with the affected drive, and add the following option:
>   nobootwait
>
> `/dev/sdax /media/drive auto rw,user,exec,nobootwait 0 0`

[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1465893)

This will obviously only work for drive mount errors not ALL errors, I'm not certain how you could ignore all errors regardless but I would think that you would want to know what the actual error is.

Comment: Nice one. It doesn't fix all boot problems, but it's a step closer, and probably as close as I'm going to get to fixing stuff like this, thanks :)