# mhddfs mount in /etc/fstab fails if periodic fsck kicks in... how to solve?

Tags: 11.10, boot, filesystem, fstab, fuse

( ubuntu oneiric 11.10 server)

Here is my /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=4e455083-9ac0-4076-ab25-dedcf461a578 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=9e691b30-8f85-4566-86cd-587de6571ce8 /storage/HDD/SAM-1500-1 ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=1888e5df-2fe5-4760-a271-09676504e168 /storage/HDD/SAM-2000-1 ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=dc321a2e-8266-42de-9b79-7a1b33eacf6c /storage/HDD/SEA-1000-1 ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=987ef5ec-01d2-4542-8e69-a38bed12ddfa /storage/HDD/SEA-1000-2 ext4    defaults        0       2
mhddfs#/storage/HDD/SAM-2000-1/Medias,/storage/HDD/SAM-1500-1/Medias,/storage/HDD/SEA-1000-1/Medias,/storage/HDD/SEA-1000-2/Medias /storage/BigData/Medias fuse defaults,allow_other,nofail 0 0
```

---

If the periodic fsck run starts during boot, my mhddfs mount fails and the server waits for a ctrl+d to continue boot...

How can I prevent the "hang" while keeping my periodic fsck runs ?

Comment: See answer to a similar question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/44019/dont-wait-for-user-input-on-errors-while-booting/115822#115822. If this helps post back and let me know

Answer (score 3):

When you look at the sixth field in your `/etc/fstab`, you see there a `0`. This means the mhddfs is not automatically fscked. So one workaround of your problem is to add `noauto` to your fstab:

```
mhddfs#/storage/HDD/SAM-2000-1/Medias,/storage/HDD/SAM-1500-1/Medias,/storage/HDD/SEA-1000-1/Medias,/storage/HDD/SEA-1000-2/Medias /storage/BigData/Medias fuse defaults,allow_other,nofail,noauto 0 0
```

So the filesystem will not automatically mounted at startup. Furthermore you write a script which basically mounts your mhddfs and add it at some late point in the boot process.

This makes sure that the `fsck` runs normal. If your system tries to mount the mhddfs, all other fscks are finished and your system should boot normal.

Comment: "Furthermore you write a script which basically mounts your mhddfs and add it at some late point in the boot process"  How do you do this?