# Xubuntu 14.04 wanting to mount nonessential drive during boot

Tags: boot, mount, xubuntu

I have a 4TB NTFS external hard drive that I keep my Movies/TV on it. For some reason, If I boot Xubuntu without the drive plugged-into the computer it will give me an answer along the lines of "Unable to mount /media/tyler/TMC_MASTER_DRIVE the drive is unplugged or unavailable. Please press 'S' to skip mounting or 'M' for manual recovery"

Why am I getting this message? The drive has nothing essential for Linux on it
(I can boot Xubuntu just fine after pressing S, it's just kinda annoying)

Comment: You may need to edit fstab file & comment (#) out the offending entry; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot