# login screen problem related to user partition

Tags: login-screen

Every time I switch on my pc, I see the screen message:
`user/local disk cannot be found please mount it manually or press 'S' to skip`

What I did was I created a `/home` partition and `local/user` partition during installation and after installation in Ubuntu I used  Gparted and merged both home and local partition. Help me how to remove this screen message.

Comment: Similar message appears for me too. But it shows something like this "**dev/mapprer/cryptswap is not yet ready please mount it manually or press 'S' to skip**". While installing Ubuntu 14.04, I had created swap partition of 4 GB but, in **System Monitor** program, under resource tab it shows **Swap not available**. How to solve this?

Comment: And @balaji, please specify which version of Ubuntu you are using. Its very necessary to consider, whether it is a bug that even others are getting already or some problem in our installation process.

Comment: [How do I avoid the “S to Skip” message on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot)