# Vagrant up/reload error - default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying…

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, elementary

I had a fully functional vagrant for three months now, but for the last three days, I am getting errors whenever I try to run vagrant up or vagrant reload.

This is the error I get when running `vagrant reload`

> ```
> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
> default: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
> default: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
> default: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
> default: capable.
> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
> default: Adapter 1: nat
> default: Adapter 2: hostonly
> default: Forwarding ports...
> default: 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
> default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
> default: Booting VM...
> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
> default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
> default: SSH username: vagrant
> default: SSH auth method: private key
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying... 
> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
> Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
> the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
> Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
> are  usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
> working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
> problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
> Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
> as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
> the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
> ```

I am using Elementary OS Luna and updated the latest versions of vagrant as well as virtualbox as some answers suggested. But the problems persist.

I have tried most of the popular solutions including enabling the GUI and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23095019/2015112). I also tried the solution given [here](http://kvz.io/blog/2013/07/25/fix-vagrant-box-hanging-at-boot/) but could not since my virtual box doesn't login.

However, the GUI presented me with this:

```
 keys: press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

I tried both the keys one by one but the problem still remains.

Has anyone had this before who could offer a solution, vagrant isn't widely covered on the web yet and I cant find a reason why this is occurring.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Elementary OS is off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to AskUbuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I avoid the "S to Skip" message on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling with all the various options available on different questions, I was still facing the same problem.
Finally, I did a

```
vagrant destroy
```

followed by

```
vagrant up
```

And I have my system working again.

Note: If you too have the habit to directly switch off your computer, you might face this problem soon! In your vagrant terminal (`vagrant ssh`), always go for a:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

or you can just type

```
vagrant halt
```

after you logout from your ssh.

PS: For those of you who might be afraid to lose your data/code/anything during `vagrant destroy`, you might relax! I was hesitant using the command, but as per the documentation, all it does is:

> This command stops the running machine Vagrant is managing and
>   destroys all resources that were created during the machine creation
>   process. After running this command, your computer should be left at a
>   clean state, as if you never created the guest machine in the first
>   place.

This implies that your code will remain intact, and the next `vagrant up` would lead you to the same state as you left, only with the problem solved now. :)

Comment: Your code will remain intact, buy your environment may have to be set up again, depending on how you set it up.