# How to mount ntfs permenantly via ntfs-3g

Tags: 14.04, mount, ntfs

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and would like to permanently mount my WD Elements external harddisk.

I currently use this to mount it manually:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

The drive normally is at `/dev/sdc1`

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /media/my_directory_here
```

I'm guessing there is a way to automatize this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Find UUID for the drive `/dev/sdc1` with `blkid` command
2. Then add a entry for the ntfs partition in `/etc/fstab`

   ```
   [partition]        [mount point]      [type]  [options]         [dump]  [pass]

   UUID=UUIDHERE...   /media/mount/point ntfs-3g defaults,nobootwait  0      0
   ```
3. `mountall`

You can also use a gui utility called [ntfs-config](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/mount-ntfs-partition-on-boot/) to automatically generate an entry for you in `fstab`

Comment: No need to reboot, run `mountall` instead.

Comment: It's also a good idea to add the `nobootwait` option, in case the external HDD is not plugged in. http://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot