# Drive fails to auto-mount at startup

Tags: fstab, disk, automount

I have a new laptop that's got both an SSD and an HDD. It's dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. The problem is that I can't seem to get Ubuntu to mount the `ext4` partition of the large storage (HDD) drive.

I used the `disks` application to set up the mount options, and it looks ok to me, but I'm no expert.

When I boot into ubuntu I get the message to "push s to skip mount".

Here's the settings I have-- can anyone advise on what's wrong or how to troubleshoot this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i mount my hdd's in:
/etc/fstab

my root filesystem

```
UUID=84a8ae47-0504-4b4a-9911-2612c4186ac7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

my ext4 hdd

```
UUID=623643e8-f7ef-4edc-9c83-7b13c89b002d   /media/Shared   ext4    defaults    0   0
```

my ntfs hdd

```
UUID=2EB81EA6B81E6D19  /media/Storage  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
```

[How do I avoid the "S to Skip" message on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot)
states that you should add "nobootwait" to the line with "nosuid,nodev..."