# How do I mount from fstab without interruption if the drive isn't available?

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, drive

I would like to have a drive mounted during boot, but only if it's available. I have an entry for it now in fstab, but if it's not available boot halts. Is there a way to have to format the fstab line so that the drive mounts if available and ignores it if it isn't?

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I avoid the “S to Skip” message on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot)

Answer (score 6):

Add the `nofail`-option to your fstab-line. Example:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/archiv  /media/archiv  ext4   rw,noexec,nofail   0   0
```

Comment: Just added 'nofail' and it works wonderfully. Thanks!